# Add firewall rule programmatically

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, firewall

I am developing an application for Mac, and wants to add firewall rule when my application launches,

would like to know the entry point, if anyone has any idea,
I guess, i need to modify
/Library/Preferences/com.apple.sharing.firewall.plist
But this file is not present in my Machine 
and any info about structure of this file ?

Requirement is something like this

When it runs, then browser shouldn't allow to open some particulars website, so i believe, this is going to be a application level firewall.

Comment: Can you clarify what you're trying to do?  Specifically, are you trying to modify the [packet firewall](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/ipfw.8.html) or the [application firewall](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1810)?  Are you trying to allow traffic to your app, or to something else (and if so what)?

Comment: [This question is a dupe of a more recent one you've asked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8604816/mac-ipfw-adding-firewall-rule). You really shouldn't post duplicate and repeated questions.

Comment: Did you ever get the problem solved? @Amitg2k12
Since `ipfw` is now deprecated you must be using `pf` now

Comment: I did this implementation on the 10.6 , and after that i didn't get chance to check it further....

Comment: can we get the status of fire wall e.g. on/off

Comment: @vikas yes its possible, please throw more detail

Comment: @Amitg2k12 I am trying to make an applicaiton that Identify if the firewall is off or on. If the firewall is off then it switch it on. I am using Cocoa with objective C and I am not able to find the solution how to do so. Thanks for reply amit

Comment: @Amitg2k12 hi i have install the HelperTool, now i want to know how add rule in firewell through Objective c cocoa Osx application? please help me. Thanks

Comment: @vikas : I am not sure,about any API to detect the firewall status @ swan , there is no interface to add firewall rule , i was running a shell script from the Cocoa Application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for looking at it, 
Finally i am using ipfw to do so, 
but still not yet clear about how to configure the rule

Comment: For anyone that will stumble upon this question/answer - 10.10+ approach is to use either `pfctl` or `/usr/libexec/ApplicationFirewall/socketfilterfw`.